# RollingFileAppender HTML-Log-File gets too large

Tags: java, xml, logging

I use the `org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger` to write `logs` into an `HTML` file with the following code.

```
<RollingFile name="RollingFileAppender"
        fileName="${log-path}/at_log(current_session).html"
        filePattern="${log-path}/Logs/at_log-%d{dd-MM-yyyy}[%i].html"
        append="true">
        <HTMLLayout charset="UTF-8" title="AdminTool log"></HTMLLayout>
        <!-- <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %style{%-5level}{reverse} 
            %logger{50} :: %method(...): %msg%n" /> -->
        <Policies>
            <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy />
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy />
    </RollingFile>
```

The problem is that the `HTML` file gets to big after time.

Is there something like a `MaxFileSize` property?

Answer (score 0):

Add a SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy in your Policies section:

```
<Policies>
    ....
    <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="500 KB" />
</Policies>
```

See [Apache documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html).